# Nightwatch.js with chromedriver not showing window switch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nightwatch.js

As we all know, you can never know too many end to end testing frameworks, and to that end I've written a basic implementation using Nightwatch.js.  Things work mostly well, however I"m noticing an issue with the "switchWindow()" function.  Basically, I launch the framework, open one window, then open a second.  I've written a function

```
function switchWindow(win) {
  client.windowHandles(function(result) {
    var newWindow = result.value[win]
    this.switchWindow(result.value[win]);
  });
}
```

which takes an input telling it which window to switch to and it should then change the window.  Control definitely is moving between the two windows.  For example, if I'm on the second window, then I call the function to switch to the first, take some action and check that the action has been successful, it makes the change on the first window and the test based on that comes back green.  However, I never actually see the browser move to the first window, it always stays on the last window open (the second one.)

The problem with this is that changes in one window change the browsers local storage, and other windows have an event listener which waits for that change and update their own page content based on those storage changes.  However, if the control is on the first window, the updates aren't properly carrying over onto the second without the windows switching back and forth.  If I pause execution (using the .pause() method) and manually click between the windows the updates take place.  If I don't the update's don't properly carry over, then when I check to see if the alternate page has updated in sync with the first the tests fail.  I can work around this but the result is an ugly test flow that is rather brittle.

So this gets back to my main question, namely why isn't Chrome actually switching between browsers instead of just bouncing control back and forth?  And is there any way to make it do so?